# Automatically remove trashed pages from nav menu

Tags: menus, pages, automation

As it is now, when a page that is in the nav menu is trashed, it still stays in the menu until manually remove via the nav menu editor. Is it possible to have trashed pages removed automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about when a page gets *trashed*? Because menu items *are* removed when you delete a page/post.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Yes, you are correct. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just hook the default `delete_post` handler for menus onto the trash action too:

```
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', '_wp_delete_post_menu_item' );
```

How simple is that!

Comment: Oh, that works like a charm! Thanks so much. Is there some easy way to have the page be brought back to the nav menu if the page is untrashed?

Comment: If you have "auto add new pages" enabled for the menu, it'll work on trashed ones too. But it won't put it back where it was.

Comment: Right. No other way? I deliberately disabled that because a new top level menu item would mess with my design.

Comment: Of course there's a way - check out `_wp_auto_add_pages_to_menu()`. That should give you ground to create a function that auto-adds trash-to-publish posts, then hook it onto `transition_post_status` :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a plugin which:

1. Adds a method to the `deleted_post` action (taking the page's id)
2. Filters: the action is used for posts etc. as well.
3. Updates the menu by

   - `wp_get_nav_menu` to get its items
   - remove the item representing the page
   - update the menu with `wp_update_nav_menu_object`.

Comment: Richard, do you mean: " *You'll need **to build** a plugin which:* " ? +1 for the blue print :)

Comment: @brasofilo Yes, if you cannot find one that already exists.